# Accessing sqlite databases on remote machine with static adress (Electron / Nodejs / fs)

Tags: node.js, sqlite, path, electron, fs

I am trying to access an sqlite file on a local area network machine located in "sqlite" folder, on windows file explorer I access it using the IP address "192.168.5.15/sqlite/db.sqlite", however when the electron aplication tries to access it, the path is converted to the local machine path "c:/application ....../192.168 ....".

please how can I just point the file directly using the static IP adress without converting it to local machine path?

here is the code:

```js
// login_app.js

var route = require('../../libs/router.js'); //my lib

var dbPath = "192.168.5.15/sqlite/db.sqlite" // here is the path i want to keep it static

function login() {
    var email         = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password    = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(email == "" || password == ""){
        alert("Please Enter Your email & Password ...");
        return;
    } else{
        var sql = require('sql.js');                            //Import sqLite 
        var fs = require("fs");                                 //Import Files driver

        var SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");               //Crypting Library

        try {
            var filebuffer = fs.readFileSync(dbPath);   //here is the problem it converts the file to local machine path c:/..../192....

            if (filebuffer != null) {
                var db = new SQL.Database(filebuffer);
            } else {
                var db = new SQL.Database();
                console.log("No Database");
            }

            // Prepare an sql statement
            var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:emailid");

            // Bind values to the parameters and fetch the results of the query
            var result = stmt.getAsObject({':emailid' : email});
            if(result.password == null) alert('Account not existing, please contact Your Administrator ...');
            else{
                if(SHA256(password) == result.password) {
                    
                    route.data.relocate('dashboard');

                }
                else alert('Wrong Login credentials, please try again ...');
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried two leading slashes?  `var dbPath = "//192.168.5.15/sqlite/db.sqlite"`   or possibly `file://192.168.5.15/sqlite.db.sqlite` - Note this page describes that sort of format but marks it "experimental" https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: file://192.168.5.15/sqlite.db.sqlite, but //192.168.5.15/sqlite/db.sqlite worked fine, thank you for your suggestion and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested by  [GregHNZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254208/greghnz) var dbPath = "//192.168.5.15/sqlite/db.sqlite" worked, so just used double slash.

Thanks [GregHNZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254208/greghnz)